# How to disable autoplay on Spotify web site?

Tags: firefox, spotify

Every time the browser starts, the music does too. Rather than navigate away (since I listen a lot) I'd like to simply *never, ever* hear music from a Spotify tab before pressing Play *somewhere*. Is it possible?